# Export and load redis database from volume

Tags: docker, caching, redis, containers

Kinda fundamental question: I'm currently trying to export my cache from a redis-container to a redis-cache on a different device by saveing the current keys, export the the .rdb file to a volume on the other device.

But restarting the redis-container/server doesn't load the "new" database from the imported .rdb file (I guess it's correctly linked to my volume and also the right path for initialization). Are there any incompatibilities or what could be the root cause of my problem?

**Update**

Well ... I just found out that the slaveof/master function of redis kinda fits all my criteria and makes stuff lot easier.